# why is my hyundai making rattling nosises when driving over small bumps in the road and clunking when turning sharply

Tags: hyundai

I have March 2012 registered Hyundai i20 classic vehicle that has a faulty timing chain. Now, the past 24 hours when driving, there are rattling sounds coming from the front drivers side when driving over small bumps in the road and a clunking sound when turning the car sharply to the left or right side.

Please advise what may possibly wrong.

Comment: It could be anything on the front drivers side suspension, it would need a visual inspection to find the cause.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I agree with @Moab that a full inspection would be needed to identify the cause. There really are *many* components that could cause those symptoms. As for the cost, that part is off-topic as it is ***highly*** conditional on *what* exactly is damaged, as well as your locality. I'd recommend removing that part of the question just to avoid it getting closed. :)